# Python prettytable get_string error

Tags: python, pandas, prettytable

I have a pandas data frame like

```
>>> df
Out[126]: 
      score        id
0  0.999989    654153
1  0.992971    941351
2  0.979518    701608
3  0.972667    564000
4  0.936928    999843
```

and want to convert to a **prettytable** (in order to write to a text file with a better readability)

```
import prettytable as pt
x = pt.PrettyTable()
for col in list(df.columns):
    x.add_column(col,df[col])
```

then inside a function, I use

```
print(x.get_string())
```

and get this error

```
File "<ipython-input-130-8db747160a67>", line 5, in <module>
verbose   = True)

File "<ipython-input-129-4e27c067e0b5>", line 104, in lda_save_eval
print(x.get_string())

File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 990, in get_string
self._compute_widths(formatted_rows, options)

File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 894, in _compute_widths
widths = [_get_size(field)[0] for field in self._field_names]

File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 894, in <listcomp>
widths = [_get_size(field)[0] for field in self._field_names]

File "C:\Users\USER\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 77, in _get_size
lines = text.split("\n")

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any clues?

Comment: have you tried get_string()?

Comment: sorry, I just made a typo right there... I have exactly tried x.get_string()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `print (x.get_string())` instead of `print(x.get_string)`

For improvement try this,
In order to write to a text file with a better readability you don't need for loop use `tabulate` it gives you more flexible.

try this,

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print (tabulate(df,df.columns,tablefmt='psql'))
```

In `tablefmt` you can provide many options to get different styles.
for more details refer this [link](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/)